# Java mocking class methods and injected services

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I need to unit test this class. I have some control over the source, but am limited in what I can do to it (it's much more complex than this, of course, and I can't do a wholesale rewrite)

```
public class MyService {
   @Inject
   private AnotherService anotherService;

   public ReturnObject MainMethod(..arguments..) {
      anotherService.someFunction(..arguments..);
      localFunction(..arguments..)
   }

   protected void localFunction(..arguments..) {
      ..code..
   }
}
```

I have access to Mockito and PowerMock. The "someFunction" in anotherService is an instance method, not static. I've tried using overrides as thus:

```
@Test
public void shouldWork() {
  MyService myService = new testMyService();
  myService.MainMethod(..arguments..);
  ..test some stuff..
}
class testMyService extends MyService {
  testAnotherService anotherService = new testAnotherService();
  @Override
  protected void localFunction(..arguments..) {}
}
class testAnotherService extends AnotherService {
  @override
  public void someFunction(..arguments..) {}
}
```

When I run this, anotherService is null. I tried both creating an actual instance of testAnotherService inside of testMyService, and injecting it with @Inject (that latter wouldn't compile).

What I seek to do is, by the tenets of "good unit testing on previously badly designed code with no tests", test all of the functionality within MainMethod, but stub/mock both the localFunctions (there are more than just the one) and the injected services, so that the only actual code under test is the code in MainMethod.

Please be gentle, long time reader, first (or nearly first) time asking!

Comment: Search for examples of @InjectMocks.  This should handle the `@Inject anotherService`.  See also: constructor injection vs field injection

Comment: I've tried some variations of that. The problem is having to test both injected methods AND local methods at the same time. I can do either, but I haven't found a way to do both. I don't want to use spy - I really want to avoid calling the real localFunction() because it has side effects and other requirements